# Node.js util.format() as String.prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create/extend the node.js [util.format](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format) function so that it can be used as a prototype (e.g.: "Hello %s".format("World")).  However, I have been unsuccessful trying it.  I have tried the following formats to no avail:

```
String.prototype.format = function(){return util.format(this, arguments)};
```

and

```
String.prototype.format = function(){return util.format.apply(this, arguments)};
```

and also

```
String.prototype.format = function(args){return util.format(this, args)};
```

None of these work. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Manuel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you would be calling it like this?

```
"%s: %s".format('key', 'val');
```

like this:

```
String.prototype.format = function(){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  args.unshift(this.valueOf());
  return util.format.apply(util, args);
};
```

In your first example, you are only passing 2 arguments, the format string, and the arguments object. You get closer with your second attempt, but the context of format should probably be `util`. You need to add `this` to the set of arguments applied to `format`. Also when working with `this` on a string, you are working with the string Object, not the string literal, so you must get the literal version using `valueOf`.